# Xbee module , using X-CTU reset

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I got this question and it might be really easy but its just something I have been wondering about I can't seem to be able to find the answer.

When my baud rate in X-CTU isn't the same baudrate as my Xbee module, it asks for a reset of the Xbee module. When I set the baudrate right it doesn't ask for a reset.

Now my question is: Does the Xbee module turn to the default baudrate for a short period of time after a reset or is it able to connect with reset because of other reasons?

So basicaly why is it able to connect using a reset? So what happens in the first period of time the Xbee module is powered on that causes the X-CTU to be able to connect to it?

Answer (score 1):

The XBee serial interface implements an auto baud feature, which works on the first single character sent to it. So when you reset the module, it is ready to accept the character and synchronize with the baud you have set, but it cannot do so again after that.

Search for the term "auto baud" in any XBee user manual to learn more about this feature.